# Unix Timestamp to CET excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, unix-timestamp

I am trying to convert a Unix Timestamp to CET
I used the formula I found in this site, asked by another user

=(A1/86400)+DATE(1970;1;1)   - since I live in German',' were replaced in formula to ';'

but it does not work for me, the result I get is #############################

for example timestamp 1629294665262271969 should give Wed Aug 18 2021 14:51:05
but I get 'dates and time that are negative or too large are shown as ######################'

I thought that it might be because it could be in milliseconds so I divided by another 1000 but the result is the same

any advice will be welcomed,
Much appreciated,

Comment: If you format the value as `General` and examine the results, you can determine that you need to divide the Unix time by `10^9`  instead of by `10^3`.  And also, don't forget to add the hour for `GMT=>CET`

Answer (score 0):

It's not in miliseconds all in seconds. Excel dating system starts from `01.01.1900` but Epoch timing starts from `01.01.1970` so we need to convert two dates to same value that's the reason why we add or remove `=DATE(1970;1;1)`

When you look at a date in excel by using `=VALUE(A1)` formula you will see some number. These numbers shows you how many days past from `01.01.1900` to given date. So you multiply the value with `86400` to convert day values to seconds. That is the idea how it works.

I wrote the formula you need but you also need to clear current format of cells if you see something like `###########` it's probably there was a date formatted value before you write the formula.

Formula examples below.

#### Date to Epoch time

`A1` is `19.08.2021`. Formula on `B1` is `=VALUE(A1-DATE(1970;1;1))*86400`. Result: `1629331200`

#### Epoch to Date time

`A1` is `1629331200`. Formula on `B1` is `=(A1/86400)+DATE(1970;1;1)`. Result: `19.08.2021`